# IntelliJ - Cannot resolve the symbol 'Arrays'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, collections

1. My code

[image: My Code]

2. SDK Level

[image: SDK & Level Settings]

3. SDK

[image: SDK]

I am using

1. Windows 7 32bit OS
2. Java version "1.8.0_221"
3. IntelliJ Idea 11.0.2

I am doing a basic program in Java. But I am getting a compilation error:

> Cannot resolve the symbol 'Arrays'

My code is this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.List;

public class EmployeesData {

    public static List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new Employee(201, "Kumar", "MS", 20000),
                new Employee(202, "Kiran", "Wells", 30000),
                new Employee(201, "Kumar", "Wells", 40000), 
                new Employee(203, "Vishal", "MS", 25000),
                new Employee(203, "Srikanth", "MS", 45000),
                new Employee(204, "Vimal", "Wells", 50000));
    }

    public static List<Employee> getEmployees2() {
        String a = null;
        return Collections.singletonList(
                new Employee(201, "Kumar", "MS", 20000),
                new Employee(202, "Kiran", "Wells", 30000),
                new Employee(201, "Kumar", "Wells", 40000),
                new Employee(203, "Vishal", "MS", 25000),
                new Employee(203, "Srikanth", "MS", 45000),
                new Employee(204, "Vimal", "Wells", 50000));
    }
}
```

I am getting the same error for **Collections** class also.

I tried in eclipse also, I am facing the same issue in Eclipse also. I tried to specify libraries also. even not solved. Might be something I have to do extra in settings.

Comment: Did you write `import java.util.Arrays;` at the top?

Comment: Beyond that: that second method shouldn't even compile. As the name states: that method creates a list around a **single** parameter passed to it. You are passing 6 args to that method call.

Comment: You could try to invalidate your cache. File->Invalidate cache

Comment: @Terje, I did same Invalidate & Restart, even not solved.

Comment: Do you have a string number in the output of compilation error? Does it indicate this file? I am asking as there is no main method there. So, maybe  `Cannot resolve the symbol 'Arrays'` error is about another file?

Comment: For your own sanity, make sure whitespace is visible. Settings-Editor-General-Appearance

Comment: Make sure you've told IntelliJ where to find the JDK.  The message suggests that you have not done that.  32 bit?  Who uses a 32 bit JDK when 64 bit is easily available?

Comment: Do you have it with any new project or only current? Try using different JDK for the project (File | Project Structure | Project -> Project SDK. Or delete and add this JDK anew.

Comment: File | Project Structure | Project -> Project SDK is a per project setting. So you will have to set this up on a per project basis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolved. I installed 15.0.6 instead of IntelliJ Idea 11.0.2. Thank you very much once again for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The following works...

```
public static List<Employee> getEmployees() {

        Employee[] e = {new Employee(201, "Kumar", "MS", 20000),
                new Employee(202, "Kiran", "Wells", 30000),
                new Employee(201, "Kumar", "Wells", 40000), 
                new Employee(203, "Vishal", "MS", 25000),
                new Employee(203, "Srikanth", "MS", 45000),
                new Employee(204, "Vimal", "Wells", 50000)};

        return Arrays.asList(e);
    }
```

...I suspect the **new** keyword is not liked by the compiler.

Comment: Sorry, it not solved, I am getting the same error in "Arrays.asList(e);" statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical behaviour you will get in case there is no project SDK defined.
When there is no project SDK none of the classes provided by the standard libraries will be available (as those are provided by the SDK).

go to module settings->project->project SDK and select a proper JDK and language level.
You may after that change that per module if needed.

Comment: I also tried them also. Please help if anything wrong. screenshot attached in top.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

`file` -> `manage ide settings`-> `restore default settings`

It will be restored and good to go!